# Redirect absolutely everything to index.php with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I use htaccess to redirect everything to /path/index.php
Absolutely everything including 404's, and non existing paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/index.php [NC,R,L]
```